# Javascript nested array and filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Here is my code

https://codepen.io/hobbesa/pen/jOGREKy?editors=1111

I am trying to get price of only weekdays.How do I do that?

```js
 this.getPriceWeekDay = this.StrategypricingDetail.map((rec) =>
      rec.map((daysOfWeek) => {
        return daysOfWeek;
      }),
```

Comment: You mean your expected result is `[30,10]` ?

Comment: Yes @SaeedShamloo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first, filter items which doesn't contain `Saturday` or `Sunday` by using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) methods, and then iterate over filtered list by [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to extract just price property, like this:

```js
let StrategypricingDetail = [ { id: 3, name: "test", price: 30, daysOfWeek: [ { id: 1, name: "Monday" }, { id: 2, name: "Tuesday" }, { id: 3, name: "Wednesday" } ] }, { id: 23, name: "Testing2", price: 10, daysOfWeek: [ { id: 1, name: "Monday" }, { id: 2, name: "Tuesday" } ] }, { id: 13, name: "Testing3", price: 14, daysOfWeek: [ { id: 1, name: "Saturaday" }, { id: 2, name: "Sunday" } ] } ];

const weekDaysPrice = StrategypricingDetail.filter(({daysOfWeek}) => !daysOfWeek.find(({name}) => name == 'Saturaday' || name == 'Sunday')).map(({price}) => price);

console.log(weekDaysPrice);
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution you could use below.

```js
 let strategypricingDetail = [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "test",
        price: 30,
        daysOfWeek: [
          { id: 1, name: "Monday" },
          { id: 2, name: "Tuesday" },
          { id: 3, name: "Wednesday" }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 23,
        name: "Testing2",
        price: 10,
        daysOfWeek: [
          { id: 1, name: "Monday" },
          { id: 2, name: "Tuesday" }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        name: "Testing3",
        price: 14,
        daysOfWeek: [
          { id: 1, name: "Saturaday" },
          { id: 2, name: "Sunday" }
        ]
      }
    ];
  
let finalList = [];  

// Create list of eligible days for the search
let daysToInclude = [
"Monday",
"Tuesday",
"Wednesday",
"Thursday",
"Friday"
];
strategypricingDetail.forEach((item, index) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < item.daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
  // Check if the day is in the eligible list
    if (daysToInclude.includes(item.daysOfWeek[i].name)) {
      finalList.push(item);      
      break;
      // When found, break out of the search after adding it to the final list.
    }
  }
});

console.log(finalList)
```

In this solution, you loop through the available items, and then compare each item's 'daysOfWeel' list with a list of eligible days.
As soon as it finds one, it'll stop searching, and add that item to a new list, until you end with the list of appropriate days.

Comment: A good answer explains how it answers the question, not just relying on code.  Even just adding comments his helpful

Comment: Apologies, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//StrategypricingDetail is the whole json
const StrategypricingDetail = [
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "test",
    price: 30,
    daysOfWeek: [
      { id: 1, name: "Monday" },
      { id: 2, name: "Tuesday" },
      { id: 3, name: "Wednesday" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    name: "Testing2",
    price: 10,
    daysOfWeek: [
      { id: 1, name: "Monday" },
      { id: 2, name: "Tuesday" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: "Testing3",
    price: 14,
    daysOfWeek: [
      { id: 1, name: "Saturaday" },
      { id: 2, name: "Sunday" }
    ]
  }
];

const weekends = ["Saturaday","Sunday"]
// Approach
// we have to filter some element based on condition
// condition will be days should not belong to weekends
this.getPriceWeekDay = StrategypricingDetail.filter((rec) => {
  for(let dayIndex = 0 ; dayIndex < rec.daysOfWeek.length; dayIndex++){
    const dayName = rec.daysOfWeek[dayIndex].name;
    if(weekends.includes(dayName)){
       return;
    }
  }
  return rec;
}).map(({price}) => price);

console.log(getPriceWeekDay);
```